# Can auto-generated Peer classes be deleted in Propel?

Tags: propel

As title, can auto-generated Peer classes be deleted in Propel? I don't know what's their purpose and i don't need them now - i'm fine using custom queries and i'm totally happy with Propel.

Deleting them would make my project a bit more clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot, it's part of Propel, and contains useful (maybe) constants.
Propel2 will remove these Peer classes, but at the moment, you cannot.